# Как увеличить размер Tilemap Collider 2D в Unity?

Tags: unity3d

Исходный вид тайла:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно чтобы collider обводил весь куб.

Tilemap Collider 2D:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Насколько я понял, у вас просто один компонент тайла, а не полностью карта. Данный коллайдер предназначен для применения на полную карту.

Comment: У меня один Sprite в котором стоит режим Multiple, и там я повырезал спрайты куба(пол), и через Tilemap сделал уровень.